# Android: error while trying to show a progressbar in asynctask

Tags: android, progressdialog

Working with Android I've got an error while I try to show a progressbar in an asynctask. I have the error at the bold line. The variable *context* is the context of the app, I'm sure. Here there's the code:

public class UpdateDBTask extends AsyncTask {

```
ProgressDialog progressDialogListFiles;
ProgressDialog progressDialogUpdateDB;

protected void onPreExecute () {
    progressDialogUpdateDB = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialogUpdateDB.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialogUpdateDB.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialogUpdateDB.setMessage("Analyzing files...");
    progressDialogUpdateDB.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialogUpdateDB.setProgress(0);

    progressDialogListFiles = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialogListFiles.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialogListFiles.setMessage("Listing files...");
    progressDialogUpdateDB.setCancelable(false);
}

protected Boolean doInBackground(String... paths) { 
    updateDB(paths);
    return true;
}

protected void updateDB(String[] paths) {

    /*.....*/
        **progressDialogListFiles.show();**
    /*...*/
}
```

}

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Why aren't you calling `show()` in `onPreExecute()`? You can't interact with the UI inside `doInBackground()`, that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: I'm calling it inside doInBackground() because I need to dismiss the progressdialog afeter a fiew seconds to show another progress dialog in this way:'protected void updateDB(String[] paths) {

    progressDialogListFiles.show();
    //do something
    progressDialogListFiles.dismiss();
    progressDialogUpdateDB.show();
    //do something
    //loop {
            //do something
            i++;
            publishProgress(i);
    //}
    progressDialogUpdateDB.dismiss();
}'
You say I can't interact with the UI inside doInBackground()...But can I interact with the UI inside onProgressUpdate()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to update the UI from a non-UI thread, namely the thread being used to process `doInBackground()`. Please update your UI from `onPreExecute()`, `onProgressUpdate()`, or `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Tomorrow I'll try ;)